# MySQL query is not running properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my code to run the mysql query, i am getting `$contactgroup` using ajax if `$contactgroup is not null or empty` it with run the query with AND but now its just running the query without and condition, i am printing the $contactgroup and $sql  its print the data but its not running the query with and condition, i have no clue why this one won't would work,

```
<?php
$contactgroup=$_GET['contactgroup'];
print $contactgroup;

$sql  = "SELECT * FROM contact where isdeleted = 0 ";
print $sql;

if ($contactgroup !="" && $contactgroup !="Empty" ){

    print "contact group is null or empty";

    $contactgroup_exp = explode(',', $contactgroup);
    $sql .= " AND contactgroup in ('".implode("', '", $contactgroup_exp)."')";  

}

?>
```

now my result for print query is

```
SELECT * FROM contact where isdeleted = 0
```

What i want like this if $contactgroup is not null or empty

```
SELECT * FROM contact where isdeleted = 0 AND contactgroup in ('xxxxxxx')
```

can anyone tell me where i went wrong,thanks

Comment: Your message `contact group is null or empty` should be in the `else` clause, not the `if` clause.

Comment: make sure you make a GET request, not POST. Try `$_REQUEST['contactgroup'];` instead.

Comment: @Barmar no i print the $contactgroup,its not null or empty its print the passed value,i dont know why its not printing the query

Comment: Your code works for me: http://ideone.com/bcW2kM

Comment: Your code is wide open for SQL injection by trusting that `$_GET['contactgroup']` follows certain conventions. Sanitize your input data!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM contact where isdeleted = 0 AND contactgroup IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: How will that test if the contact group matches the ones in `$_GET['contactgroup']`?

Comment: SELECT * FROM contact where isdeleted = 0 AND contactgroup IS NOT NULL and contactgroup in ('xxxxxxx')

Comment: You don't need the `IS NOT NULL` test if you're testing with `IN`. If it's `NULL` it won't match anything.